# Can not RESET MASTER on MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

When I try to run the command `RESET MASTER`, I get the following error:

`Binlog closed, cannot RESET MASTER`

I double/triple check the configuration and the option `bin_log` is defined.

Comment: We had a problem with the restart of mysql. We had a bad debian-sys-maint password. MySQL never stops but also never writes any errors.

Comment: Sorry I mean our problem is now solved. The solution was to kill the server because it didn't stopped. We were trying to change our Master.